# Setting default value to an HTML dropdown

Tags: html

I have created a dropdown menu in html. I have a reset button which resets all the value to null. But on clicking this I need to reset the dropdown menu to the first value which I gave in the  field.

Please help...
The code for the dropdown is as below.

```
    <select name="abc" id="abc">
      <option value="one">One
      <option value="two">Two
    </select>
```

But on clicking Reset I am getting a blank in the dropdown list from where i have to again select either One or Two.
Instead I want it to automatically set to the value "One".

Comment: kindly post your js code also.

Comment: what is your reset code?

Comment: This is my reset code

        <input type='button' class="btn btn-primary" value='Reset' name='reset' onclick="return clearForm(this.form);">
    <script>
       function clearForm(form) {
       var $f = $(form);
       var $f = $f.find(':input').not(':button, :submit, :reset, :hidden');
       $('#msg').empty();
       $f.val('').attr('value','').removeAttr('checked');
       }
    </script>

Comment: Why are you setting `value` to `''` in your last line of reset code.

Comment: You should try something like -  `$('#abc option:selected').removeAttr('selected')`. It will just remove `selected` attribute from the `option` which is already selected and your HTML drop down code will automatically show first option in select drop down after reset.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use the [`selected`](https://html.com/attributes/option-selected/) attribute for the item that you want to be the default:

```
<select name="abc" id="abc">
  <option value="one" selected="selected">One</option>
  <option value="two">Two</option>
</select>
```

If you are manually performing the reset, you'll likely want to store a reference to the current selection *prior* to resetting them and using that to retain the previous selection, which you can access via the [`selectedIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/selectedIndex) property. Depending on your use case and technology (e.g. jQuery, etc.), you can select a specific element by its index, value, or potentially other attributes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use add the attribute `selected` to the option you want to be default like this:

```html
<select name="abc" id="abc">
  <option value="one">One</option>
  <option value="two" selected>Two</option>
</select>
```

Or add `selected="selected"`:

```html
<select name="abc" id="abc">
      <option value="one" selected="selected">One</option>
      <option value="two">Two</option>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add `selected` attributes to make default select.

```
<select name="abc" id="abc">
  <option value="one">One
  <option value="two" selected="selected">Two
</select>
```

With jquery

```
$("#abc").val("two")
```

Answer (score 0):

> use **selected**

here live example https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_selected.asp

```
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="vw">VW</option>
  <option value="audi" selected>Audi</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this code in your reset jquery function.

```
    $("#abc option:selected").prop("selected", false);
    $("#abc option:first").prop("selected", "selected");
```

Comment: Tried this. It is not working. Actually after clicking the reset the value becomes null. But i need the value which is first in the options list even after resetting the form.

Comment: @KapilViswam then you avoid null value for dropdown in reset.this code automatically select first in the options on reset

Comment: eg: $f.val('').attr('value','').removeAttr('checked'); I think you need remove to avoid null

Answer (score 0):

[HTML select drop down](https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_elem_select) by default shows first option if none of the option is selected. So, effectively you just need to clear the `selected` attibute for your dropdown.

```js
function clearForm(form) { 
  //var $f = $(form); 
  //var $f = $f.find(':input').not(':button, :submit, :reset, :hidden');     
  //$('#msg').empty(); 
  $('#abc option:selected').removeAttr('selected');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="abc" id="abc">
    <option value="one">One
    <option value="two" selected>Two
</select>
<input type='button' class="btn btn-primary" value='Reset' name='reset' onclick="return clearForm(this.form);">
```